# What game is this d6 with a blank two for?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

All the other sides have numbers on them, except the side that would have a two, which is instead blank, as shown in the picture.

What game would this die be for?

Comment: Do you know this is intentional, and not just a manufacturing mishap?

Comment: What are the other faces of the dice?

Answer (score 4):

Considering that that looks like a very generic die it might actually not be from a game but instead from a magic trick / illusionist kit.
I'd post a link to the various online stores that offer them, but none of them had a whole lot of information about how the trick would work.
It boils down to switching it out with a regular die though.
[image: Horrible looking cover that doesn't even show the missing two]

Of course it very well might be from a board game, but custom dice tend to have some flairs or branding or even a colour.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility. Although, from what I can gather from online sources, the gimmick dice used for forcing tricks like this typically have one of the numbers appearing twice (typically on opposite sides of the die, so you won't notice it so easily), rather than one side being completely blank. I'm not sure what a blank-faced die would be good for in a magic trick, since a gimmick like that would seem kind of obvious.